# My Solidity Assembly Code does not work. It gives me execution reverted error. Now I can't figure out where I made a mistake

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, inline-assembly

My code does not work for some reason. It gives execution reverted error, even though I have followed all the documentations and tutorials correctly.

```
    function swapEthForToken(
        address router,
        uint256 minAmount,
        address[2] calldata path
    ) public payable {
        assembly {
            let deadline := add(timestamp(), 300)

            mstore(0x7c, SWAP_ETH_FOR_TOKEN)
            mstore(0x80, minAmount)
            mstore(0xA0, path)
            mstore(0xE0, address())
            mstore(0x100, deadline)

            let s1 := call(gas(), router, callvalue(), 0x7c, 0x100, 0x00, 0x40)

            if iszero(s1) {
                revert(3, 3)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1) On which network you're testing the code? 2) What are your input params?

Comment: Could you also show the exact error?

Comment: I am testing it on bsc mainnet

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.